# REMOTE_ADDR disappears when running XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, web-config, rules, transformer-model

I have created a block rule for my website where I'm listing a few IP-addresses that are allowed to access the Admin-page of my website.
The condition looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='adminBlockRule']">
    <xsl:comment>Blockera Admin för alla utom vissa IP-adresser</xsl:comment>
    <rule name="adminBlockRule" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(Admin/|Sysadmin/).*$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <conditions>
        <xsl:comment>Generell</xsl:comment>
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10.*.*.*" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="194.103.31.*" negate="true" />
        ... More rules
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
    <xsl:comment>Hit</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
```

When I put it in my web.config file it works fine, but when I put it in my web.production.config-file and run it with XSLT it removes the "{REMOTE_ADDR}" so the output looks like this:

```
<rule name="adminBlockRule" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(Admin/|Sysadmin/).*$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <!--Generell-->
            <add input="" pattern="10.*.*.*" negate="true" />
            <add input="" pattern="194.103.31.*" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

I'm using version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:saml="urn:dk.nita.saml20.configuration"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl saml">
  <xsl:output method="xml"
              indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Comment: You should edit your question to show the XSLT you are using, as code is very hard to read in comments. Also, can you show the XML in which `REMOTE_ADDR` is set. Thank you.

Comment: @TimC thank you for the comment, I have updated my question. Hope I understood your feedback correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by adding a extra pair of "{}" in the input parameter and that did the trick. 
New conditions looks like this:

```
<add input="{{REMOTE_ADDR}}" pattern="10.*.*.*" negate="true" />
<add input="{{REMOTE_ADDR}}" pattern="194.103.31.*" negate="true" />
```